# What is AzureAttestService?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019

We started the installation and configuration of SQL Server 2019 on Windows 2019 and noticed after install a new service named 'AzureAttestService' was running and set to automatic. Services list the Description and Group field also as AzureAttestService. Below are a few questions:

- What is the purpose of this service?
- What is the relationship with SQL Server 2019?
- Any negatives of stopping and disabling this service?

I've researched, but haven't found much information on AzureAttestService.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This service has to do with the Always Encrypted with Enclaves feature.  I have sent a note to the team to get this more explicitly documented for customers.  Some scenarios will break if that service is not enabled.

You can find additional details about Azure Attestation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/attestation/overview).